# When do we use "@" in Razor

Tags: razor

I am reading a example from a book like this:

```
@switch ((int)ViewBag.ProductCount) {
                case 0:
                    @: Out of Stock
                    break;
                case 1:
                    <b>Low Stock (@ViewBag.ProductCount)</b>
                    break;
                default:
                    @ViewBag.ProductCount
                    break;
            }
```

so my question is how do we determine when and where do we need the "@" ? for example `ViewBag.ProductCount` does not have it but then in `case 1:` it does have it.

Comment: Try this http://bit.ly/1o4IGTx

Comment: @DavidG Will do, In the mean time you can try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqJPOIhL6b0

Comment: Thought I was going to get Rickrolled there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the @ sign before the start of a code block:

```
@{
    // code here
 }
```

Or before a control of flow statement that appears within mHTML markup@

```
@if(this || that){
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
}
else
{
    <h1>Good bye</h1>
}
```

Or before a server-side statement, expression or value that needs to be rendered to the browser:

```
@Datetime.Now // will render the current time to the browser 
@(2/2 == 1) // will render 'true' to the browser
```

You can read more at my site here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/153/Inline-Razor-Syntax-Overview